# Como utilizar arquivos HTML da pasta assets em uma WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

Sei que existe diversas perguntas parecidas com essa, mas em todas elas não encontrei nenhum método que me ajudasse.

**Como está na activity:**

```
package com.example.guilherme.webviewteste;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webTeste();
}



public void webTeste(){

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String path="file:///assets/mathscribe/";
    String js = "<html><head>" + "<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+path+"jqmath-0.4.3.css'>"+"<script src='"
            +path+"jquery-1.4.3.min.js'></script>"+"<script src='"+path+"jqmath-etc-0.4.5.min.js'></script>"+
            "</head><body>"+"<script> var s = '$ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a=0$' M.parseMath(s);document.write(s);</script></body></html>";
    webView.loadData(js, "text/html", "UTF-8");

}
}
```

**Como está no XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.guilherme.webviewteste.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
</WebView>
```

**Print da organização do projeto:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Print de como fica o resultado final no Smartphone:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Deveria ser carregado a expressão que está nesta linha

```js
 var s = '$ax^2+bx+c=0$ with $a=0$';
 M.parseMath(s);
 document.write(s);
```

Comment: por via das duvidas coloca um html qualquer dentro de body e me diz que se a tela ainda esta em branco

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu fiz um teste e funcionou, o que poderia ser então o problema?
Agora eu fiquei bem mais perdido :/

Comment: GuilhermeHS acho que já ocorreu comigo algo assim, na hora de compilar e executar de alguma forma não atualiza o app no emulador

Comment: Tenta usar o [`loadDataWithBaseURL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadDataWithBaseURL\(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String\)) passar o `path` como `baseUrl` e nos seus  `<script src='"+path+"...` coloque apenas `<script src='./seuarquivo.js'>`.  Se isso não funcionar você tambem pode tentar criar uma index.html nesse diretorio e usar o [`loadUrl()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadUrl\(java.lang.String\)) usando `file:///assets/mathscribe/index.html` como url

Answer (score 0):

Você não está fechando seu `HTML`. Insira depois de sua `</body>` o `</html>`.

Comment: Não funcionou da mesma maneira, vou editar e arrumar aqui, porque eu editei isso aqui já, mas o problema persiste.